# mod_wsgi setup in production failed to start

Tags: django, ssl-certificate, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a django project in production using ubuntu, and I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPz0s1CQsTE&t=6s) explaining how to setup and run mod_wsgi in production. Upon running `apachectl start` I get the following error

```
apachectl start
AH00526: Syntax error on line 53 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/django_project-le-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.dimsum.dk/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Prior starting the apachectl I did the followings:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

The installation was successful and I then put `mod_wsgi.server` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` under `settings.py`. I then run without problem

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi \
--server-root/etc/wsgi-port-80 \
--user www-data --group www-data \
--port 80 --setup-only
```

Then I stopped my current apache2 server by

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Followed by

```
/etc/wsgi-port-80/apachectl start
```

and got the error

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 53 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/django_project-le-ssl.conf:
    SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.dimsum.dk/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
    Action 'start' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

When running with sudo the problem is solved.